# openssl "error: undefined reference to" in Android

Tags: android, ssl, openssl

I obtained the library built to use [openssl](https://github.com/leenjewel/openssl_for_ios_and_android?tab=readme-ov-file) on Android from the link below.

I created a `CMakeLists.txt` file and an `openssl Lib` directory in the `app` directory as described in the link.

- opensslLib

```
- arm64-v8a
  - lib
    - libcrypto.a
    - libssl.a
    - libcurl.a
    - libcurl.la
  - include
    - curl
    - openssl

- armeabi
  - lib
    - libcrypto.a
    - libssl.a
    - libcurl.a
    - libcurl.la
  - include
    - curl
    - openssl

- armeabi-v7a
  - lib
    - libcrypto.a
    - libssl.a
    - libcurl.a
    - libcurl.la
  - include
    - curl
    - openssl

- mips
  - lib
    - libcrypto.a
    - libssl.a
    - libcurl.a
    - libcurl.la
  - include
    - curl
    - openssl

- mips64
  - lib
    - libcrypto.a
    - libssl.a
    - libcurl.a
    - libcurl.la
  - include
    - curl
    - openssl

- x86
  - lib
    - libcrypto.a
    - libssl.a
    - libcurl.a
    - libcurl.la
  - include
    - curl
    - openssl

- x86_64
  - lib
    - libcrypto.a
    - libssl.a
    - libcurl.a
    - libcurl.la
  - include
    - curl
    - openssl
```

- CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/zlib/include")
set(ZLIB_LIBRARY_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/zlib/lib")

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/opensslLib/${ANDROID_ABI}/include)

add_library(ssl STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(ssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/opensslLib/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libssl.a)

add_library(crypto STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(crypto PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/opensslLib/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libcrypto.a)

add_library(curl STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(curl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/opensslLib/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libcurl.a)

add_library( native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/native/file1.c
             src/main/native/file2.c
             ...
             )


target_link_libraries( native-lib
                       ssl
                       crypto
                       curl
                       android
                      )
```

I expected it to compile normally.
But I get an error:

```
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_expand_block: error: undefined reference to 'inflate'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_compress_block: error: undefined reference to 'deflate'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_finish: error: undefined reference to 'inflateEnd'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_finish: error: undefined reference to 'deflateEnd'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_init: error: undefined reference to 'inflateInit_'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function zlib_stateful_init: error: undefined reference to 'deflateInit_'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_free: error: undefined reference to 'inflateEnd'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_free: error: undefined reference to 'deflateEnd'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_ctrl: error: undefined reference to 'deflate'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_ctrl: error: undefined reference to 'zError'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_write: error: undefined reference to 'deflate'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_write: error: undefined reference to 'zError'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_write: error: undefined reference to 'deflateInit_'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_read: error: undefined reference to 'inflate'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_read: error: undefined reference to 'zError'
  ../../../../opensslLib/armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a(c_zlib.o):c_zlib.c:function bio_zlib_read: error: undefined reference to 'inflateInit_'
```